# Keras bug NasNetlarge no top

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, convolutional-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am trying to use `NasNetlarge` in Keras without the top but I cant get rid of the top:

```
from keras.applications import NASNetLarge
model = NASNetLarge(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, 
                    weights="imagenet")
```

If I use any shape other than the (331, 331, 3) shape, I get the error that I must use (331, 331, 3) if I `include_top=True` even though I set `include_top=False`. If I set the input shape to (331, 331, 3) and `include_top` to `False`, it downloads the weights with the top. Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the Keras module?

Comment: It might be a good idea to post this on the Keras GitHub issues board, if you haven't already. If you have, link it in your question too for future reference.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, should I close this question then?

Comment: Perhaps someone will still answer it here. You could add some more information or code so people can eaily run a test (i.e. provide a minimum working example). Perhaps a moderator will be able to provide better assistance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For me the error even shows up running the code above.

Answer (score 0):

What is your keras version? Two things you could try are:

1. Update your keras to latest version
2. If the above does not work, open the nasnet.py file in keras, and change this part of the code:

   ```
   elif default_size == 331:  # large version
       if include_top:
           weight_path = NASNET_LARGE_WEIGHT_PATH
           model_name = 'nasnet_large.h5'
       else:
           weight_path = NASNET_LARGE_WEIGHT_PATH_NO_TOP
           model_name = 'nasnet_large_no_top.h5'

       weights_file = get_file(model_name, weight_path,
                               cache_subdir='models')
       model.load_weights(weights_file)
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   elif default_size == 331:  # large version
       if include_top:
           weight_path = NASNET_LARGE_WEIGHT_PATH
           model_name = 'nasnet_large.h5'
       else:
           weight_path = NASNET_LARGE_WEIGHT_PATH_NO_TOP
           model_name = 'nasnet_large_no_top.h5'

       weights_file = get_file(model_name, weight_path,
                               cache_subdir='models')
       model.load_weights(weights_file, by_name = True)
   ```